# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Error: NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST error opening Firefox v103.0.2 with GeckoDriver v0.31.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

*Firefox v103.0.2* (current) when initiated with latest *GeckoDriver v0.31.0* and *Selenium v4.4.0* crashes with *`NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST`* error as follows:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Error: NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST
```

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Log

import sys
print ("Python Version: " +str(sys.version_info))

import selenium
print("Selenium version: " +selenium.__version__)

log = Log()
log.level = "trace"
options = Options()
options.add_argument(log.level)
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Console output, traceback and error stacktrace:

```
Python Version: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Selenium version: 4.4.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\debanjan.bhattacharj\Desktop\Python Programs\Selenium_Firefox_tests.py", line 26, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 177, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 276, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 369, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 434, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Error: NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST
Stacktrace:
#checkLoadingState@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.jsm:239:28
onStateChange@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.jsm:284:28
```

Where am I wrong? Anybody facing the same?

Comment: you might want to check your HOSTS file for a "localhost" entry.  If it is there, it should be set to "127.0.0.1"... if not, try adding that.  Sounds like something's blocking localhost from resolving (maybe blocked by port??)

Comment: I tried to reproduce this on my machine. I was getting the following error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Error: NS_BINDING_ABORTED
Stacktrace:
#checkLoadingState@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.jsm:216:28
onStateChange@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.jsm:261:28`

But when I commented the line  `options.add_argument(log.level)`, I was able to execute the code without any error. I know the error is not the same as you got, but thought to share it in case it helps you resolve this.

Comment: @ketanvj Please help us to debug and fix the issue by updating your observations in the [GeckoDriver issue](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/2036).

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I am not able to reproduce this scenario on my machine. I am on Windows, with the Selenium 4.4.0, Python 3.10.2 and the above code is working fine after commenting options.add_argument() line.

Comment: same issue, any advice?